# Error message from console stating that res is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently trying to build a fullstack application using javascript(node.js). My goal is to create a weather API with dummy data and everything was going well until I reached the end portion where I am trying to get the users search results to show up below the search box. I've tried using a fetch API from my main js file to retrieve data from my index.js file (which contains the server, imported data, etc.) but I continue to get an error message from the console stating that 'res' is not defined. 'res.data.city' is what I am using to acquire the input information from the user and render it to the screen but I keep getting told that it is not defined; I believe that it should be coming from the index.js file. Here is my code. (PLEASE be nice guys. I am a new developer and am just trying to better myself at programming.)

script.js file (main javascript file that is linked to html document)

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');

const textInput = document.getElementById('city');

let city = textInput.value;

textInput.addEventListener('input', (e) => {

    city = e.target.value;

})

const getData = () => {

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/weather/?city=' + city)

    .then(res => {

        return res.json();

    })

    .then(resData => {

        console.log(resData)

    }).catch((error) => {

        console.log(error)
    });

};


form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

    e.preventDefault();

    getData()


    let location = document.querySelector('.cityName');

    let celsius = document.querySelector('.celsius')

    let fahrenheit = document.querySelector('.fahrenheit')

    let error = document.querySelector('.error')

    if(res.data.city) {

        location.innerHTML = 'City: ' + res.data.city;

        celsius.innerHTML = 'Temperature (C): ' + res.data['temperature (C)']

        fahrenheit.innerHTML = 'Temperature (F): ' + res.data['temperature (F)'];

    } else {

        error.Message.innerHTML = 'SORRY! This city is not currently in our 

database :{'

    }

    textInput.value = '';
})
```

index.js(file with the server running)

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors')

const fakeWeatherData = require('./data.js')

app.use(cors());    

app.get('/weather', (req, res) => {


    let cityName = req.query.city.toLowerCase();

    for(let i = 0; i < fakeWeatherData.length; i++)

    if(!cityName) {

        res.send({"status": "error", "message": "Please enter a city name"})

    } else if (cityName === fakeWeatherData[i].city.toLowerCase()) {

        return res.send(fakeWeatherData[i])
    }


    res.send({"status": "error", "message": "Sorry! This city isn't in the database :{"})

})
```

index.html(main file that will be rendered to broswer)

```
<body>

 <div class='main'>

     <form>

         <label for='city'>City:</label>
            <div class='city-box'>


          <input type='text' placeholder='Please enter a city' id='city' name='city' require>

         </div>     

         <button type='submit'>CLICK</button>

     </form>   

 </div>

    <div class='error'></div>

    <div class='weather'>

     <h1 class='cityName'></h1>

     <h4 class='celsius'></h4>

     <h4 class='fahrenheit'></h4>

 </div>


 <script src="./js/script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Between `getData()` and `if(res.data.city) {...`, no data is passed. Did you mean `var res = await getData()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GaloisGirl is correct, `res` is not defined because you are not defining `res` within the scope of the anonymous function where you set the `submit` event listener.

Given that you're not already using `async`/`await`, seems best to stick with promise notation so it would look something like this:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

  e.preventDefault();


  let location = document.querySelector('.cityName');

  let celsius = document.querySelector('.celsius')

  let fahrenheit = document.querySelector('.fahrenheit')

  let error = document.querySelector('.error')

  getData()
  .then((res) => {
    if(res.data.city) {
      location.innerHTML = 'City: ' + res.data.city
      celsius.innerHTML = 'Temperature (C): ' + res.data['temperature (C)']
      fahrenheit.innerHTML = 'Temperature (F): ' + res.data['temperature (F)']
    } else {
      error.Message.innerHTML = 'SORRY! This city is not currently in our database'
    }

    textInput.value = ''
  })
})
```

And you'll also want to return the promise from `getData`

```
const getData = () => {

    return fetch('http://localhost:3000/weather/?city=' + city)


...OTHER STUFF
```